# Django's Relationship with Java EE,ASP.NET & PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, django, jakarta-ee

Django is a ~new~ programming language (compared to Java EE, Asp.Net and PHP).

What are similar aspects of django that are in Java EE, Asp.Net and PHP?

For Example. Django has very similar URL patterns to Java EE.

Thanks,

-R

Comment: Django is not a programming language  at all.  What are you saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> similar aspects of django that are in Java EE, Asp.Net and PHP?

- Django is a framework.  It uses Python as a language.  Embedded in Apache, it's a nice way to serve web content.
- Java is a Language.  Some folks like Tomcat as a framework.  Some don't.  If you write JSP pages, it's a nice way to present web content.
- ASP.Net is both language and run-time library with web page template features.  It usually works with IIS to create a nice way to serve web content.
- PHP is a language with web page template features.  It usually works with Apache to create a nice way to serve web content.

Interestingly, Django cannot be compared with the other technologies.

Also they're all -- in some vague way -- part of serving web content.  Sort of.

Comment: Tomcat isn't a framework, it's a web server that implements the Java EE specification.  Struts2 is a framework, Spring MVC is a framework, there are many other Java frameworks.  Tomcat isn't.

Comment: "3. ASP.Net is both language and run-time library with web page template features. It usually works with IIS to create a nice way to serve web content.
4. PHP is a language with web page template features. It usually works with Apache to create a nice way to serve web content." Nice....

Answer (score 0):

Django isn't a language, it is a web framework for python. J2EE and ASP.net are also both frameworks, but really not terribly appropriate for anything except for internal enterprise apps (you can use them for other things, but that is what they are developed for and work best for). PHP is a language which has similar frameworks to django, but PHP itself isn't really the same type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

django is not a new programming language, it is a new web framework based on python. python to django is like php to code igniter(or cakephp)